# react-fontawesome icons does not appear

Tags: reactjs

I installed the package like it is here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-fontawesome and I tried to use it but no icons visible, any idea ?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import FontAwesome from 'react-fontawesome';

export default class Header extends Component {

    state = {
        showNav: false
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="open_nav">
                  <FontAwesome name="rocket"/>

            </div>

        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like below

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faChevronDown } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

    export default class Header extends Component {

        state = {
            showNav: false
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <div className="open_nav">
                      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faChevronDown} />
                </div>

            )
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to either import CSS from CDN or add it in your build process.

From the library:

> Note: This component does not include any of the Font Awesome CSS or
>   fonts, so you'll need to make sure to include those on your end
>   somehow, either by adding them to your build process or linking to CDN
>   versions.

So, all you need to do is add this to your `index.html`:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```